# Подсветка div при наведении

Tags: html, jquery

[image: Video player]

Я бы хотел сделать подсветку блока при наведении как слева и плавную анимацию исчезновение.
Как это можно реализовать?
И второй вопрос, как мне сделать превью видео каким как на рисунке?(чёрный экран и по центру оранжевая кнопка).

Comment: Используй :hover для подсветки пи наведении, а по превью, используй картинку, при клике на нее, прячь ее и воспроизводи видео

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что на SO обмениваются опытом и помогают друг другу, а не выполняют работу за других...

Comment: Приложите код что вы сделали уже, что не получилось!

Answer (score -1):

> Я бы хотел сделать подсветку блока при наведении как слева и плавную анимацию исчезновение. Как это можно реализовать?

Вам нужно к блоку, в который входит текст и видео, добавить свойство `transition: all linear .2s;` и ховер-эффект (`:hover`), который будет менять цвет фона блока на ваш. На скрине примерно так `:hover {background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);}`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  background: url('http://barrysakkers.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/solid-baby-blue.jpg') no-repeat center center / 100%;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all linear .2s;
}

.item:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.video::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="text">Morbi ac lobortis nisl, nec gravida metus.</div>
    <div class="video"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="text">Morbi ac lobortis nisl, nec gravida metus.</div>
    <div class="video"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> И второй вопрос, как мне сделать превью видео каким как на рисунке?(чёрный экран и по центру оранжевая кнопка).

Можно использовать такой вариант, правда костыльный :D

```js
$('.video').on('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('played');
  $(this).find('iframe').click();
});
```

```css
.video {display: block; width: 300px; height: 150px; position: relative; cursor: pointer;}
.video::before, .video::after {content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 1;}
.video::before {width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}
.video::after {width: 0; height: 0; border: 20px solid transparent; border-left: 30px solid yellow; left: calc(50% - 15px); top: calc(50% - 20px);}

.video.played::before, .video.played::after {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="video">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IsZDtOYUWvk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```